# DriveApp not retrieving file from Google drive in apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, mailmerge

So I've been messing around for a while now with the Mail Merge for Gmail using Google sheets:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/samples/automations/mail-merge

I wanted to include an attachment feature that could be automated as well (for sending individual passes for a concert, if you must know). So I did so by first automating name and detail addition to the passes in python using PIL, uploaded it to my drive and sent it all out by making a couple changes to the script (enclosed in the line made with hyphens).
So it worked on my first try, sending out 500 invitations in a matter of minutes with no problems.
But it didn't work for exactly 4 participants:
[image]

So I sent these out 4 manually for the event. But I wanted to know why it didn't work. So I went into the script, put in a couple console.logs, used the debugger to figure out where it went wrong. Turns out that the DriveApp.getfilesbyname was returning an empty iterator specifically for these files. I double and triple checked, and the files for these records were also in the drive, in the same location as all the other files that got sent out.

```
obj.forEach(function(row, rowIdx){
    // Only sends emails if email_sent cell is blank and not hidden by a filter
    if (row[EMAIL_SENT_COL] == ''){
      try {
        const msgObj = fillInTemplateFromObject_(emailTemplate.message, row);

        // See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)
        // If you need to send emails with unicode/emoji characters change GmailApp for MailApp
        // Uncomment advanced parameters as needed (see docs for limitations)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
        att=DriveApp.getFilesByName(row["Attachments"])
        console.log(att)
        emailTemplate.attachments=[]
        emailTemplate.attachments.push(att.next())
        console.log(emailTemplate.attachments)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        GmailApp.sendEmail(row[recipient_COL], msgObj.subject, msgObj.text, {
          htmlBody: msgObj.html,
          // bcc: 'a.bbc@email.com',
          // cc: 'a.cc@email.com',
          // from: 'an.alias@email.com',
          name: 'Avenues, SJMSOM IIT Bombay',
          // replyTo: 'a.reply@email.com',
          // noReply: true, // if the email should be sent from a generic no-reply email address (not available to gmail.com users)
          attachments: emailTemplate.attachments,
          //inlineImages: emailTemplate.inlineImages
        });
        // Edits cell to record email sent date
        out.push([new Date()]);
      } catch(e) {
        // modify cell to record error
        out.push([e.message]);
      }
    } else {
      out.push([row[EMAIL_SENT_COL]]);
    }
  });
```

So someone help me figure out what I did wrong (I'm a student, you see, so it'd be useful if I figure out these kinds of errors) or if I didn't, how do you report this to google?

Comment: How can I reproduce the problem?

Comment: Not know what `obj` is and how it is structured, there is no way anyone can help you.  I suggest you include a lot of `console.log()` calls to print out each of the `obj` properties as your code progresses through the process.

Comment: By any chance, have you sent more than 500 invites in one go? If so, you have hit the quota of sending the maximum messages per day or the unique recipients per mail which both have a count of 500.

Comment: @Cooper, sorry about this, but you can't. it was some kind of drive storage issue

Answer (score 1):

I ran through all the code and the DriveApp implementation. Then ran the same code on a different Mail account due to @Cooper's suggestion. Turns out it actually was a DriveApp problem but not because of the function, but actually the Drive storage itself.

**Easy Fix**: Delete all files facing the problem from the Drive and reupload them to fix the issue. Drive storage sometimes doesn't store properly during huge uploads which messes up file search through DriveApp